# SQL Unique index preventing all Db inputs from all data from a Json API

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am pulling in and parsing data from and API which displays xml data. I have created some unique indexes on my SQL tables to prevent duplicates but they seem to prevent the code from parsing in data that is not already in the Db.

This is the unique index i have created  and should not allow a row entry if the 3 columns are already in the database

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX My_Index
ON [FourDayAggrRollingWindForecastSemoes (LOAD_FORECAST_ROI, LOAD_FORECAST_NI, AGGREGATED_FORECAST);
```

C# code:

```
using (SemoDbContext context = new SemoDbContext())
{
    // Enter The Node 
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        FourDayAggrRollingWindForecastSemo fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast = new FourDayAggrRollingWindForecastSemo();
        // Get all attributes from the node
        foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
        {
            LoggingInfo log = new LoggingInfo();
            fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.loggingInfoID = logInfoID;

            switch (attribute.Name)
            {
                case "TradeDate": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.TRADE_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(attribute.Value); break;
                case "StartTime": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.START_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(attribute.Value); break;
                case "EndTime": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.END_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(attribute.Value); break;
                case "DeliveryDate": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.DELIVERY_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(attribute.Value); break;
                case "LoadForecastROI": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.LOAD_FORECAST_ROI = Convert.ToDecimal(attribute.Value); break;
                case "LoadForecastNI": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.LOAD_FORECAST_NI = Convert.ToDecimal(attribute.Value); break;
                case "AggregatedForecast": fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.AGGREGATED_FORECAST = Convert.ToDecimal(attribute.Value); break;
            }
        }                       

        // UK Start Time 
        fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.UK_START_TIME = fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.START_TIME.AddMinutes(minutes);
        // UK End Time
        fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.UK_END_TIME = fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast.END_TIME.AddMinutes(minutes);

        context.FourDayAggrRollingWindForecastSemo.Add(fourDayAggrRollingWindForecast);

        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Without the unique indexes all the data parses to the Db ok, but with the index, I get the below error even when the data is not currently in the Db.

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_UniqueFileds'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'WindForecastSemoes'.
>
> The duplicate key value is (Aug  2 2019 12:00AM, Aug  1 2019 10:00PM, Aug  1 2019 10:15PM, Aug  1 2019 12:00AM, 93.81, 33.65, 127.46).

Comment: Check if the data already exists before inserting?

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges` wraps the  modified entities into a transaction thus if one insert fails, the whole transaction is rolled back. Either check if the data already exists and remove the entity from the change tracker or change the way you save the data i.e calling `SaveChanges` after each record is processed.